# What is the node.js equivalent of this curl request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I'm trying to create a node app that can transmit data to a Motu audio device over HTTP.

I need a way to achieve the following in Node.js,

```
curl --data 'json={"mix/chan/0/matrix/fader":0}' voyager-audio-core.local/datastore
```

I tried the following, with no luck:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'voyager-audio-core.local/datastore',
    { "/mix/chan/0/matrix/fader" : 0 },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a syntax issue since the request() function only takes two arguments according to the [docs](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback). Does the following code work?

```
let options = {
  url: 'voyager-audio-core.local/datastore',
  body: 'json={"mix/chan/0/matrix/fader":0}'
}

request.post(options,
  function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body)
    }
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately not, the console.log returns undefined.

Comment: I think the problem has more to do with the Motu API and less with this response not going through, so I'm going to close the question.  Thank you for helping though!

Comment: Ah okay, sorry we couldn't reach a more tangible solution. Best of luck!